# Using grep and ls in FTP client?

Tags: ftp, grep, ls

How could I use `grep` and `ls` in FTP client...

I mean if I want to find some specific file I could use:

```
 ls -l | grep pattern
```

Comment: You would need to explain the question a bit more? What FTP client?

Comment: @Vijay:I mean I want the functionality to list files on the ftp server and use grep to fliter the result.I am using ftp command under Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) can, exactly the way you typed.

Answer (score 9):

With the usual Unix commandline interactive ftp, one approach is:

```
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> dir . foobar
output to local-file: foobar [anpqy?]? y
500 Unknown command
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,149,140,15,195,159)
150 Accepted data connection
 11966       5.26 KB/s 
226-Options: -a -l 
226 156 matches total
ftp> !grep con foobar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 11050207   users          911007 Sep 13  2007 accu_pyconc.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x    1 11050207   users         9805405 Mar 25  2009 pycon_abst.pdf
```

i.e., get the dir results into a local file first, *then* run grep locally.  Incidentally, this lets you run multiple greps after paying for just one `dir` data transfer;-).

Comment: Thanks.So is it means that no ftp client support shell like feature e.g. pipe or even build-in call(I mean without '!') to other command like grep...

Comment: @jcyang, not in the stock ftp interactive command-line client that comes with Unix &c, but of course you can write a different client: SO is about developing software, NOT about using existing programs (see serverfault and superuser for **that**), right?  So grab starting source code in the language of your choice, e.g. for python plenty of examples at http://www.example-code.com/python/pythonftp.asp , and get coding to make a new client program with exactly the functionality you think it should have!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can do this with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) for any protocol, including the FTP:

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@example.com" ^
    "ls /path/*.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

References:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_ls

Answer (score 0):

You can mount an sftp folder to a host where you have permissions to use grep or any tool.