# How to use GREP in FTP client where Destination Machine is Unix based

Tags: ftp

How to use GREP in FTP client where Destination Machine is Unix based?
I want to find files containing specific string amoung all files but i can not initiate telnet session. I can only initiate FTP session and needed to find files/string in various folders & subfolders. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

grep is not part of the standard ftp commands. I'm afraid you'll have to make do with ls. As far as I know it doesn't support searching through subfolders though. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618611/using-grep-and-ls-in-ftp-client) for another client.